# Affect only the onhover div tag with JQuery and SLidedown() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to create a JQuery slidedown() function that will be assigned only on the div where the mouse is focusing on.

This kind of thing is possible with the combination of JQuery but I managed to achieve only this: I can make it work only if every div has separate class. If I name them the same, it will open (slide down) all of the div tags on the hover of the first div.

So, I hope it is an easy solution that I cannot see.

My code is below:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GzxJf/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="q1">1. Question (on hover)<br/>
<div class="desc1">Description: Here goes the question one from the php variable</div>
<br/></div>
<div class="q2">2. Question (on hover)<br/>
<div class="desc2">Description: Here goes the question two from the php variable</div>
<br/></div>
<div class="q3">3. Question (on hover)<br/>
<div class="desc3">Description: Here goes the question three from the php variable and so on</div>
<br/></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    (function (i) {
        jQuery('.desc' + i).hide(); 
        jQuery('.q' + i).hover(
            function () {
                jQuery('.desc' + i, this).stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                jQuery('.desc' + i, this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);            
            });
     }(i));
  }});
```

**CSS**

```
.desc1,.desc2,.desc3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.q1,.q2,.q3 {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

So, this is working when there is only 3 questions, but what about a hundred? With my code it will be pointless to create css for every div, so I know there is a simple solution :) or not :(

Answer (score 1):

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GzxJf/4/

The Script:

```
jQuery(".desc").hide();

jQuery(".q").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".desc").stop().slideDown("slow");
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".desc").stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution that may work for you:

**[*Updated Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/GzxJf/5/)**

Since you don't know how many questions there may be, or if some will be loaded or removed dynamically, I would delegate off of the wrapping element (in this case the document). Then all you need to do is be consistent with your classes in the questions.

EDIT - In the hopes to avoid confusion, I've gone ahead and updated this to add a wrapping element to avoid binding on the document. See below:

HTML:

```
<div class="q-wrapper">
    <div class="q">1. Question (on hover)<br/>
    <div class="desc">Description: Here goes the question one from the php variable</div>
    <br/></div>
    <div class="q">2. Question (on hover)<br/>
    <div class="desc">Description: Here goes the question two from the php variable</div>
    <br/></div>
    <div class="q">3. Question (on hover)<br/>
    <div class="desc">Description: Here goes the question three from the php variable and so on</div>
    <br/></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.q-wrapper').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.q', function(e){
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter'){
        $(this).find('.desc').stop(true, true).slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.desc').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice indeed but i got concerned with your approach of binding event handler on document!
So i went on and asked about this from other pals :) check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204156/binding-event-on-document-performance-concerns

Comment: They make excellent points, but I wouldn't recommend binding on the document element either . As I said in my answer I would wrap all of your question element in a container, and bind off of that. so `<div class="questions-container">` and then `$('.questions-container').on(...`

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a parameter this which will point on the divs where the mouse cursor is. So, actually, this will work fine as you can see in my fiddle below.

Just change a little your code (css classnames and jQuery elements) and it will work.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GzxJf/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="q">1. Question (on hover)<br/>
<div class="desc">Description: Here goes the question one from the php variable</div>
<br/></div>
<div class="q">2. Question (on hover)<br/>
<div class="desc">Description: Here goes the question two from the php variable</div>
<br/></div>
<div class="q">3. Question (on hover)<br/>
<div class="desc">Description: Here goes the question three from the php variable and so on</div>
<br/></div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    (function (i) {
        jQuery('.desc').hide(); 
        jQuery('.q').hover(
            function () {
                jQuery('.desc', this).stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                jQuery('.desc', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);            
            });
     }(i));
  }});
```

CSS

```
.desc {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.q {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: what if the question and answers are more or less then the number in the loop