# Binding event on document performance concerns

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, events, document

Does binding an event on document have any performance concerns?

i.e:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter'){
        $(this).find( //some element and do something...
```

Vs

```
$(".myElement").hover(function(){
    $(this).find( //some element and do something...
```

I think keeping a track via document will use more processing power then assigning the event only a limited DOM elements?

Comment: Yes, yes. Why would you need to put the handler at the `document` level?

Comment: Every mouseenter and mouseleave that happens on every single element will bubble up and trigger the event on the document level, you're better off binding to the elements themselves.

Comment: I don't think the performance impact would be significant.

Comment: is there any way i can run a test... is there any way to find out how much load JS events handler are taking...

Comment: In addition to what adeneo says: and `e.stopPropagation()`;

Comment: what does stopPropagation() does?

Comment: @ImranBughio when it is called in an event handler, it prevents the event from bubbling up any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to implement a performance test to be sure about the actual difference, but I guess it should be a minimal impact, because binding events on the document will mean that you catch any element event once it *bubbles* to the top-most element in the document.

Anyways, skipping the "performance argument", your case looks better when you bind a handler on the nearest parent. It's not only about performance: it's more logical.